# Push an android studio project under a specified directory on an organization repository in GitHub

Tags: android, git

I created an organization (team project) and already made a repository. On this repository, I created a folder called "Android" so I can put everything that is Android related in that folder. So I researched a bit and found the following commands:

`git init
git remote add origin https://www.gihub.com/xyz/abc.git
git add --all
git commit -m "Commit Message"
git push origin master`

my problem is that it uploads the project folder and additional files like gradle stuff on the repository root directory and I want **everything to be in the "Android" folder**. Do i just edit each file and add them to the Android folder like this [github_editfile_change_directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OG8UY.png)
(I'm afraid that on a new push or pull it won't recognize the files it sent before since their path changed) or are there any additional commands i need to type in the console?

forgive me please I'm a newbie :-)

Comment: What's your problem then? Did you push the project? What's the expected result and what's the actual result?

Comment: I did push and this is the result I got: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hipqxii5zDVJ2esT2Lnf6FqLLnRUVhkE/view?usp=sharing, what i wanted is that everything would be inside the folder "Android" so I reverted for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create new "Android" folder locally and move all files there.

Then run following commands:

`git add .`

Check that files were added to folder:

`git status`

`git commit -m 'some message here'`

`git push origin master`

Comment: Thank you so much!! I don't know how I didn't think about such a simple solution before...